# Ordering contents of T-SQL STRING_AGG()

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by, string-aggregation

I need help!

I have this query

```
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT * 
FROM    [dbo].[Conversion_imageTiles]
WHERE   [old_file] = 'tileWeir-E-W-U-D.gif'
ORDER   BY [old_file],[static_class]
```

It produces these results..

[image]

Notice the field [static_class] is in alphabetical order....

But this is a sub query...

```
SELECT   [old_file]
         ,STRING_AGG(CONCAT([static_class],' ',[rotation]),' ')[static_class]
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT * 
        FROM    [dbo].[Conversion_imageTiles]
        WHERE   [old_file] = 'tileWeir-E-W-U-D.gif'
        ORDER   BY [old_file],[static_class]
) a
WHERE [old_file] = 'tileWeir-E-W-U-D.gif'
GROUP   BY [old_file]
ORDER BY [old_file],[static_class]
```

See, there it is in the middle - popping out a result set that has [static_class] in alphabetical order..
So why are the results of the full query this..

[image]

Notice [static_class] is backwards, I would expect it to start with 'bypass-weir..'
Changing the ORDER clauses has no effect... its ALWAYS in that order...

Help!

EDIT:
I wondered if it was due to the internal ordering based off the [id] column in the internal sub query.

Removing it:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [old_file],[static_class],[rotation] 
FROM   [dbo].[Conversion_imageTiles]
WHERE  [old_file] = 'tileWeir-E-W-U-D.gif'
ORDER  BY [old_file],[static_class]
```

Had no effect

Comment: Please avoid posting image. use formatted text instead

Comment: Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) use `WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ...)`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My bad - replaced images of code with actual code blocks instead.

Comment: @Squirrel WITHIN GROUP(), is the answer. If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as such,